# Default sort of Python not working as expected with float32

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I am trying to sort a relatively large list of numpy.float32 (74K items).

I am sure that there is a 0.0 element, so when I use the sort method, it should be the first one. (There are no negatives).

I plotted the list after ordering and there is a weird pattern. Am I missing something?

I made the following verifications:

1. All of the elements of the list are
2. The result of calling min(list) return always 0.0. But the first item of the list is the 0.67. (the 0.0 has an index around 48k as you can see in the picture)

Find the list attached in the txt. (https://ufile.io/95v6ap4q)

[image: Plot of the sorted list]

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: It is clear that your code to do the sorting isn't working the way you expect. But if you want us to suggest why, you need to show us the code.

Comment: Try to fix the English as well... + `min(list)` will return the minimum. If the minimum is 0.0 at position 48k, then this is what will be returned. If you want to return the first item, you need to use `list[0]`.

Comment: @Mathieu, after ordering the list with the sort method, I think that the first element should be the 0.0, that is why it is ordered

Comment: @BorjaPerezdeGuzman True. I was simply pointing out that `min(list)` will return always 0.0 no matter the order. Reread the bullet point 2. from the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably be using [`np.sort()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) instead, if it's a NumPy array.

Comment: already tried but it returns some nan values when in the original list there are non nan.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, sorry.

Comment: @BorjaP Running `np.isnan(x).any()` on your data yields `True`.

Comment: In fact, `grep -n nan myoutfile.txt` prints several `nan`s too.

Comment: You are right, It is because of the nan values. With the sort default method, the list is broken into peaces as shown in the graph but with the numpy, it puts the nan at the end. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

**Taking a guess**; do you have something like...?

```
np.sort(alist)
plot(alist)
```

If so you're plotting the still unsorted list; np.sort is a function returning a new list, it doesn't sort your list in-place.

You need something like...

```
blist = np.sort(alist)
plot(blist)
```

Comment: already tried. I tried with the default sort of python and the return is the attached image in the description. With np.sort it creates some NaN values

Comment: np.sort won't create NaN values, it will optionally put them at one end of the result or the other.  I can only echo an earlier comment and suggest that you post some code to show exactly what you're doing or people here are can only guess what the problem may be.